# How to access azure Dev Ops data such as Changeset between dates using python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to connect to AZURE Dev-Ops and acquire change set information to automate the release notes preparation using PYTHON.

Upon reading the documentation and the process provided in from [github](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api) link, i have used the following:

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
import pprint

# Fill in with your personal access token and org URL
personal_access_token = 'mypattokenvalue'
organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/myorg'

# Create a connection to the org
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)
tfsv_client = connection.clients.get_tfvc_client()
project_name="myprojname"
search_criteria=".item_path='$/myprojname/Trunk/Main',.fromDate:'01-01-2019',.toDate:'11-13-2019-2:00PM'"

changeset_info = tfvcclient.get_changesets(project=project_name,search_criteria=search_criteria)
```

Upon executing the code it threw the error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'item_path' in following line of code of the package eventhoughi provided Item_path value:

   255         if search_criteria is not None:
--> 256             if search_criteria.item_path is not None:
    257                 query_parameters['searchCriteria.itemPath'] = search_criteria.item_path
```

I have tried to give the search criteria in form of dictionary also that also gave the same error. If do not give Item path at all it throws the same error.

Hence i am not sure how to provide the data into the search criteria parameter to the get_changesets method.

I request help from any one on how to provide the data so that i can query the information of changeset using date range under main branch of a given project from AZURE Dev Ops using PYTHON?

**Adding additional queries to the existing post- update on Nov 15 2019:**

Is this a defect/bug in the package as it is not taking the values however i try to provide or the way i provided the search criteria is wrong?
If this is a legitimate issue,can you please let me know where can i log a defect against it?
If the values provided or the way i have provided the values are wrong can you please show/explain me the correct way?

Thanks in Advance

Regards

ChaitayaNG

Comment: According to your error message, it is not defect/bug in the package. Your `search_criteria` variable type is not support this way `search_criteria.item_path` of getting value. I think you should change your `search_criteria` type, to make sure you can get the `item_path`,`fromDate`,`toDate` successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error indicates that `str' object has no attribute 'item_path'`. The variable **search_criteria** you defined is a `str` type. You cannot get the attribute `item_path` which does not exist for str search_criteria.

You should define an object type of search_criteria Please check below code for example.

```
  search_criteria = type('',(object,),{"item_path":'$/myprojname/Trunk/Main',"fromDate":'01-01-2019', "toDate":'11-13-2019-2:00PM'})
```

Comment: As i tried to explain above if i create a search criteria in form dictionary also i get same type of error stating: 'dict' object has no attribute 'item_path' and in the same line of code. In fact i tried to execute the code as is by providing the search criteria as you have defined by replacing the project name with actual project name but i get the same error. Can you please provide inputs again on the same? Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: I update above answer to define search criteria as an object. now item_path can be referred by `search_criteria.item_path`.

Comment: Thanks Levi for the quick resolution and time. It worked at my end. But can you please let me know how you have come to the conclusion or how could you deduce that the search criteria should have been passed as object type? I just wanted to know this information to improve my knowledge so that i can use this approach in other areas also when in need.

Comment: From the error you posted, we can know that the code treats item_path as the attribute of search_criteria. And if we define  search criteria as str or dict. then  item_path is not it's attribute. I also check the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/blob/dev/azure-devops/azure/devops/v5_1/tfvc/tfvc_client.py) to make sure that  search criteria should be defined as an object with item_path as it attributes